# Is it possible to refresh the TabbarController when a user selects a particular tab in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

I have a TabbarController with 3 tabs with each tab representing a navigation Controller. What I would like to do is when a user selects a particular tab the whole tabbar Controller should refresh.

To make it more clear...

When a user selects tab0 and navigates in that tab 2-3 times and then the user selects tab1. Now when the user again selects tab0 it retains the last viewed ViewController. Can 
I make to show the first viewController in that tabbar NavigationController.

Can anyone help me in resolving this problem...

Any code will be very helpful...

Thanx in advance...

Plz help me.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set yourself as the tab bar delegate and implement tabBar:didSelectItem: as per below.

You can then popToRootViewController on your relevant ViewController:

```
- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item
{
    if (item.tag == kRelevanTabBarIndex) {
        [self.relevantNavController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    }
}
```

Cheers,
Rog